# face recognisation and registration in python validating exixted user atthe time of face registration

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

registering  phase:
1)  1st user enter some string(any name), I am taking 10 images from CAMERA, continuously 10 images one after the other and placing them inside the folder name(string given by the user as mentioned above in the same para)
2) then passing that folder to get trained

Issue:

while  registering the unknown faces these are   the following issue:
1) when user enter the name, example "xxx" and  10 pictures gets clicked and trained, now next time also the same person Sneha is registering herself with different names, such as "xyzz" again 10 picture getting clicked and trained     now one person gets trained  number of times, I want to obstruct that process, how I am supposed to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the model.predict() on the 'new' face images and if that face is familiar and associated with some other name, you can just delete that new folder